# How to import users in users table mysql using drupal 7?

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

How can i import users in user table(mysql). I am using drupal 7. Please help me out. thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [Feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/feeds)